# PO Box Address regex issue

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
@"(?i)\b(?:p(?:ost)?\.?\s*[o0](?:ffice)?\.?\s*b?(?:[o0]x)?|b[o0]x)"
```

Can someone help me identify the issue and correct this regex to catch the scenarios I need it to and allow others to pass?

It looks like this is catching any address that contains 'Po' at any point.

For example:

```
123 Polar Road
165 Super Point Drive
```

etc... would all fail.

I need it to catch:

```
P.O. Box 123
PO Box 123
PO 123
P0B 123
Box 123
Post Office Box 123
```

Looks like when I made the B optional this occurred. but I need the b to be optional to catch PO 123.

Comment: A little data sanitation before trying to parse the data would go a long way.

Comment: Here's a handy link for testing regex: http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Comment: Is this solely for US addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
@"(?i)\b(?:P(?:[0o]st|.?) ?0O? ?(?:B(?:.|[0o]x)?)?|B[0o]x) *([0-9]+)\b"

should catch all the examples you listed

Comment: This works perfectly for all the scenarios I need and appears to be allowing valid addresses. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this?

```
\b[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\b
```

Comment: Misses "PO 123" and "P0B 123".

Comment: This does not catch scenarios PO 123 and POB 123.

Comment: because your pattern, and the one Wayne is adapting, has [B|b][O|o|0][X|x] at the end of it. Now, riddle me this: how does "PO 123" have "box" at the end of it?